# php - shortcut for creating dynamic array with meaningful key names

Tags: php, regex

I have some logic that builds a multi-dimensional array based on matches found in a regex. I call the explode function,using a delimiter. 
Everything works and my array looks like this:

```
 Array ( 
  [0] => 
    Array ( 
        [0] => A1 
        [1] => 100/1000T 
        [2] => No 
        [3] => Yes 
        [4] => Down 
        [5] => 1000FDx 
        [6] => Auto 
        [7] => off 
        [8] => 0 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
        [0] => A2 
        [1] => 100/1000T 
        [2] => No 
        [3] => Yes 
        [4] => Down 
        [5] => 1000FDx 
        [6] => Auto 
        [7] => off 
        [8] => 0 
      ) etc.etc...
```

In order to keep the code in the front end "dumb", i want to change the keys from numbers to strings that represent what the values are.  These strings will be used as column headings in a table.  So for example:

```
 Array ( 
  [0] => 
    Array ( 
        [port] => A1 
        [Type] => 100/1000T 
        [Alert] => No 
        [Enabled] => Yes 
        [Status] => Down 
        [Mode] => 1000FDx 
        [MDIMode] => Auto 
        [FlowCtrl] => off 
        [BcastLimit] => 0 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
        [port] => A2 
        [Type] => 100/1000T 
        [Alert] => No 
        [Enabled] => Yes 
        [Status] => Down 
        [Mode] => 1000FDx 
        [MDIMode] => Auto 
        [FlowCtrl] => off 
        [BcastLimit] => 0         
               ) etc.etc...
```

Here's the code that generates this array:

```
  $portdetailsArray = array();
  foreach ($data as $portdetails) {
    $pattern = '/(\s+)([0-9a-z]*)(\s+)(100\/1000T|10|\s+)(\s*)(\|)(\s+)(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)(\s+)(1000FDx|\s+)(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)(\w+|\s+)(\s*)(0)/i';

   if (preg_match($pattern, $portdetails, $matches)) {

        $replacement = '$2~$4~$8~$10~$12~$14~$16~$18~$20';
        $portdetails= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $portdetails);
        array_push($portdetailsArray, explode('~',$portdetails));
   }

}
```

I guess instead of using the explode function, I can manually loop through my string.  Each time I find a "~", i know it's the start of a new field so i can add they key /value pair manually. 
But I was just wondering if anyone had ideas on other ways to do this. 
Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to do? which is the input array and which is the output array?

Comment: `$2~$4~$8~$10~$12~$14~$16~$18~$20` is wrong. here `$20` will be `$2` before `0`

Comment: @shiplu - my code is building the arrays that you see at the start of my post.  what i want to do is change my code so that the keys are names instead of just numbers. you'll notice in the code that explode() is being used, which is why it's building an array with numeric keys by default.

Comment: @shiplu - i don't understand what you mean about the regex.  it's working just fine for me.

Comment: You don't need parenthesis around the \s, nor around the |, so you could have only 9 capture groups instead of 20.

Comment: could you show some sample `$portdetails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reply to your original question, you could use the `array_combine` function, to replace the keys.

```
$row = explode('~',$portdetails);
$row = array_combine(array(
       'port',
       'Type',
       'Alert',
       'Enabled',
       'Status',
       'Mode',
       'MDIMode',
       'FlowCtrl',
       'BcastLimit'), $row);
```

But even better, you should use the clearer (verbose is clearer in this case)

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $portdetails, $matches)) {
    array_push($portdetailsArray, array(
       'port' => $matches[2],
       'Type' => $matches[4],
       'Alert' => $matches[8],
       'Enabled' => $matches[10],
       'Status' => $matches[12],
       'Mode' => $matches[14],
       'MDIMode' => $matches[16],
       'FlowCtrl' => $matches[18],
       'BcastLimit' => $matches[20]));
}
```